# auto generating unique id in PHP where i could specify the starting number of the id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an office management system using PHP and mysql(back-end) where i will be entering details of new employees in a module. Now i want to automatically generate an unique id for them starting from '1' and with a prefix "EMP". Can anyone help me out??

Comment: you want in sequential i.e 1,2,3,...

Comment: Yes. With a prefix EMP. Like EMP1, EMP2, ...

Comment: then you can increment by "EMP".$i+1 will do it know

Comment: Okay. Let me try. I'm actually very new to this and learning. So wat i asked may seem very easy. thanks btw.

Comment: use loop and increment value by 1 that will do like "EMP".$i+1

Answer (score 1):

First you need to identify the largest employe id from your database. For that the query will -

```
SELECT MAX(TRIM(LEADING 'EMP' FROM `employee_unique_id`)) as emp_id FROM `table_name`;
```

Next you need to increment it by 1. So the complete code will be -

```
$db = new mysqli();
$db->connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, SQL_DB);

if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// GET LAST UNIQUE ID
$query  = "SELECT MAX(TRIM(LEADING 'EMP' FROM `employee_unique_id`)) as emp_id FROM `table_name`;";
$result = $db->query($query) or die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');

// ADD +1 WITH LAST UNIQUE ID
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$last_emp_id = empty($row['emp_id'])?0:$row['emp_id'];
$next_emp_id = 'EMP'.($last_emp_id+1);

print_r($next_emp_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

use loop

```
for($i=0;$i<=any number;$i++)
{
$employees="EMP".$i;//append emp prefix and auto generated number $i
}
```